# Using MSGraph to download emails for Exchange Online with Advanced Threat Protection (ATP) Enabled

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft365-defender

We have a process that downloads emails, using MSGraph, at regular intervals (for example...every 10 minutes).
Once downloaded, the emails are examined and attachments are imported for additional processing.

We have a customer who moved to Office 365 Exchange Online and has Advanced Threat Protection enabled.

We are downloading the emails, but a subset of the emails (typically emails that were received within a minute of when we initiated the download) are failing.
We assume that these emails have not had the ATP post-delivery protections scan executed on them...yet.

Is there a method to filter out Emails that are still waiting for the ATP post-delivery protections to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with ATP (and I don't have permissions for ATP in my tenant), but you can try to call `/informationProtection/threatAssessmentRequest` endpoint and filter mail threat assessment requests.

```
GET /v1.0/informationProtection/threatAssessmentRequests?$filter=contentType eq 'mail'
```

It will return collection of [mailAssessmentRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailassessmentrequest?view=graph-rest-1.0).

`mailAssessmentRequest` has properties `messageUri` and `status`.

`messageUri` is the resource URI of the mail message for assessment. The value should look like this (according to this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/informationprotection-list-threatassessmentrequests?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1))

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/messages/{message-id}
```

You can parse the `message-id` from `messageUri` and pair it with `message-id` of the current processed email and check `status` of `mailAssessmentRequest` whether is pending or completed.